# How to get more information than username about current user in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm beginner in programming and I've got a problem with select data from database. I can get current user username (in my database it's unique for every user). I'd like to get from database more information about this user - Id, name, surname. I don't know how to do this.

I made DbContext:

```
namespace Aplikacja.DAL
{
    public class AplikacjaContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Konto> MojeKonto { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is in my controller:

```
public ActionResult MojeKonto()
{
    var konto = new Konto
    {
        pesel = User.Identity.Name,
    };
    return View(konto);
}
```

This is part of model:

```
public class Konto
{
    public int idUzytkownik { get; set; }
    public string imie { get; set; }
    public string nazwisko { get; set; }
    public string pesel { get; set; }
    public string haslo { get; set; }
}
```

I use "pesel" as username.

I tried something like this in controller:

```
var user = from u in ***
       where u = User.Identity.Name
       select u
```

***- here I've got a problem, because intelisence doesn't see database. Should I change something in my program or try different way?

Comment: What do you want the data to come from?

Comment: Can you show us some code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Looks OK so far. Are you using Entity Framework to access the database? Then you should probably have a `DbContext` with a `DbSet<Konto>` somewhere from which you can select the user. [Tutorial: EF6 Code First using MVC5](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Thank you for help. I had to do DbContext as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fine to load from the database using the username found in `User.Identity.Name`.

Code similar to the below will do what you need and get you the full user object from your database, you simply need to instantiate your `DbContext` before using it in your proposed LINQ query. That's why it didn't work. Also,
using `SingleOrDefault` (as below) is also a better idea as it will pull out the only record (or none if it can't be found) since they're unique anyway.

```
public ActionResult MojeKonto()
{
    // Initialise a blank variable for if they're not logged in, or are an invalid user
    Konto konto = null;
    // Only try to load if they're logged in
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
        // Instantiate the DbContext to connect to database
        using(var db = new AplikacjaContext()) {
            // Attempt to load from database using Username, note that 'OrDefault' means if it doesn't exist, "konto" variable will stay null
            konto = db.MojeKonto.SingleOrDefault(m => m.pesel == User.Identity.Name);
        }
    }

    if (konto == null) {
        // You could do something here if you can't load more detail about the user if you wanted
    }

    return View(konto);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You're answer helped me a lot. I've got one more question. I've got a problem with representation data in view. I tried @konto.imie but 'konto does not exist in current context'. What do you recomend?

Comment: In the View you need to set it to have a model (the type of konto), search for more info on Model. Then you would use Model.imie to access the data in the view.

Comment: I put '@model Aplikacja.Models.Konto', am I thinking right? I did it at first and '@Model' causes error : „Object reference not set to an instance of an object”

Comment: Yes that is pretty much correct. Are you sure you're getting a value back? Put `return Content($"No user found for {User.Identity.Name}");` into the last `if` statement in my sample code so you can see if it's being populated.

Comment: Do you understand how to debug the code? Set a breakpoint on `if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)` and go from there. Make sure that value is true, then make sure `User.Identity.Name` has a value, etc. If everything looks good, check your database to make sure you have a user with that name. How exactly are you logging into your application? Are you sure you're logged in?

Comment: I had a problem with DbContext, but now everything works as I want. Thank you very much for help :)